# What are some of the most culturally universal names?

Tags: culture, language, names

This is mostly a shower-thought type query rather than an active problem I'm looking to solve, but here it goes.

Say I have a character that gets an opportunity to choose his own name, and he wants to choose a name that can fit in anywhere and seem relatively inconspicuous, no matter where he travels.

If the setting is Earth and the cultures and regions are similar, then the main regions/languages I'd try to match are english, asian (chinese, japanese, etc.), slavic (russian, polish, etc.), indian (hindi, urdu, etc.), romance (french, spanish, etc.), african, etc.

If the setting is more esoteric (magic or space) with alien lifeforms or weird fictional cultures, then its difficult to even define the cultures and their languages and naming conventions, much less the names, so let's go with examples like [dothraki](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Dothraki), [elvish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvish_languages_(Tolkien)), or [the dragon language](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Language), as some to maybe try to fit into.

To make this remotely possible, I've been ignoring the spelling/written form of the name and going with only that's being spoken, so this allows homophones, and if even that's too difficult, maybe names that at least sound very similar. So far I've mostly thought of one-syllable names like Lee (Li, Lee-uh), or Wren (Ren, Rin, etc), or May (Mei, Meh, Mai, etc.), which can fit some of the groups above, so I'm wondering what everyone has heard/can come up with.

They also don't need to *completely* universal and fit all possible regions, but I'm wondering what are the most encompassing ones.

Comment: Hi SpyGuy, unfortunately, this site doesn't deal well with brainstorm like questions, you need to be a little more specific, as told by the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question *might* -emphasis on might ^^'- be better received if you focus on intersecting between a few nations/culture only, skipping fictional ones for instance. That way people will have an easier time answering, and the opinion-inducing bias of putting our culture's most common name on top is less likely.

Comment: Also and it's part of focusing, are you looking for feminine or masculine names? Perhaps ones which could match the two genders?

Comment: In Chinese, Lee/Li is a family name, not a given name. Monosyllabic Chinese *given names* are very rare.

Comment: You're asking about the actions of an individual character, not establishing some fact about a specific fictional world. Such questions are inappropriate for this site.

Comment: VTC: Under the right conditions we'll answer a question about the process of developing names, but we do not answer questions about what would be the best/good/useful/etc. name. If you roll your mouse over the [tag:name] tag, you'll see that it specifically excludes its use for this kind of question. The problem is that names are 100% subjective and story-based.

Answer (score 2):

**Dan**

Daniel is an Old Testament character and so a name used in cultures with Abrahamic religions (Hebrew, Christian, Muslim).  Hindi has [Dhan](https://www.kidpaw.com/names/dhan).  "Dan" is also a popular name in China, Japan and Korea.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_(name)

It is a popular, common name.  "Dan" is easy to say for speakers of any language and hard to mistake with the hard start and soft end.

Comment: What is written Dan in Pinyin is not pronounced like what is written Dan in English. And in Chinese, the various forms written Dan in Pinyin are family names, not given names. As a rule of thumb, Chinese given names are meaningful two-syllable compounds, e.g., Zedong "Eastern Lake" (Mao), Jinping "Easy Calm" Xi.)